# Django | Reverse accessor for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair'

Tags: django, django-models

Al crear nuevo modelo, me devuelve el siguiente error. Es como si tuvieran incompatibilidad de nombres, pero los nombre de los campos son diferentes. ¿Qué puede ocurrir? Gracias.

Error:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
repair.Repair.affectedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.placedDevice_repair'.
repair.Repair.affectedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.removedDevice_repair'.
repair.Repair.placedConsumable_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedConsumable_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedConsumable_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.placedConsumable_repair' or 'Repair.removedConsumable_repair'.
repair.Repair.placedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair'.
repair.Repair.placedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.removedDevice_repair'.
repair.Repair.removedConsumable_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedConsumable_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedConsumable_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.removedConsumable_repair' or 'Repair.placedConsumable_repair'.
repair.Repair.removedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.affectedDevice_repair'.
repair.Repair.removedDevice_repair: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Repair.placedDevice_repair'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Repair.removedDevice_repair' or 'Repair.placedDevice_repair'.
```

Archivo models.py

```
class Repair(models.Model):
    datetime_repair = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha actuación',null=True, blank=True)
    incidence_repair = models.ForeignKey(Incidence, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    affectedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    typeFailure_repair = models.ForeignKey(TypeFailure, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    typeRepair_repair = models.ForeignKey(TypeRepair, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    removedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    placedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    removedConsumable_repair = models.ForeignKey(Consumable, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    placedConsumable_repair = models.ForeignKey(Consumable, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    statusAfterRepair_repair = models.ForeignKey(StatusAfterRepair, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    summary_repair = models.TextField('Resumen',null=True, blank=True)
    detail_repair = models.TextField('Detalles',null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tienes varios ForeignKey a una misma tabla, debes agregarle un related_name diferente a cada uno, de lo contrario, adopta por defecto el mismo related_name para todos y te da ese error. Por ejemplo:

```
affectedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True,related_name='affectedDevice_repair')
placedDevice_repair = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True,related_name='placedDevice_repair')
```

Ahora debes hacerle eso a todos los campos de la tabla Repair con ForeignKey de las tablas Device y Consumable.

Comment: Ok! Y qué sentido tiene eso. En un ManyToMany entiendo que se crea tabla intermedia y necesita un nombre seguramente, pero en el caso de ForeignKey ¿Por qué nombrarla? Gracias Firefly!